# LINQPad's db view populate duplicate local server when click on a section of samples

Tags: linqpad

When I click each sample on the samples section, in chapter 19. from numeric type unification to Dynamic Objects- dynamic XAttributes, my database tree view keep populating my local database server with a "." Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the C# 4.0 IAN samples library that was fixed recently - download the samples again and the problem should disappear.